# Using Ubuntu Server machine as a DHCP and DNS server to forward URL's to IP addresses

Tags: server, dns, dnsmasq

I'm inexperienced with Linux servers but I've done okay so far - basically I want this machine to dish out IP addresses via DHCP (done) and then I also want it to act as a DNS server that simply sends you to a certain IP address when you enter a specific URL. That IP will be local, on the same subnet. I've done plenty of research but can't find anything specific to my issue.

I'm using isc-dhcp-server in combination with dnsmasq (could not get the DHCP feature on it to work - maybe using just that would be a better option?) and the DHCP is giving machines the correct DNS address too - the same as the DHCP server of course. The output when trying to use `nslookup xyz.com` on a Windows client that's been given a DHCP address from the server, is Server: UnKnown although the Address is correct, and something about a non-existent domain, followed by the requests to the DNS server timing out. Sorry I can't give much more detail, but I don't know where else to turn but to ask online. Settings below are a result of trying to follow a few different tutorials, guides, and my own experience. Censored where needed.

dnsmasq.conf

```
no-dhcp-interface=
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.hosts
```

dnsmasq.hosts

```
192.168.88.5 www.xyz.com
192.168.88.5 xyz.com
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.1.1        CExxx.xxx.local CExxx
192.168.88.5     xyztestsite
#ipv6 stuff below
```

dhcpd.conf

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.88.255;
option routers 192.168.88.1 #this ip does not actually exist
option domain-name-servers 192.168.88.2;
option domain-name "ubuntuserv.local";
subnet 192.168.88.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.88.11 192.168.88.250;
}
```

Thanks very much for any help my way.